# I am struggling to save data into postgreSql table using typeORM and Nestjs with one to many relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have 2 entities i.e Customer, Orders with one to many relationship. A customer can have multiple orders and an order can be owned by only one customer. I am creating an api to create order that is a `POST` api.

`order.controller.ts`

```
@Post()
async createOrder(@Body() order: CreateOrderDto) {
  const newOrder = await this.orderService.createOrder(order);
  return newOrder;
}
```

`order.service.ts`

```
constructor(
  @InjectRepository(Order)
  private orderRepository: Repository<Order>,
) {}


async createOrder(order: IOrder) {
  const newOrder = this.orderRepository.create(order);
  await this.orderRepository.save(newOrder);
  return newOrder;
}
```

`create-order.dto.ts`

```
export class CreateOrderDto {
 @IsString()
 @IsNotEmpty()
 @Length(5, 400)
 public description: string;

 @IsNotEmpty()
 @IsNumber()
 @IsPositive()
 public amount: number;

 @IsNotEmpty()
 @IsString()
 public paymentMethod: string;

 @IsOptional()
 @IsString()
 public customizeName: string;

 @IsOptional()
 @IsString()
 public weight: string;

 @IsNotEmpty()
 public customer: ICustomer;

 @IsNotEmpty()
 @IsArray()
 public products: Array<IProduct>;
}
```

I am sending this json from postman

```
{
   "description": "Customized waullet",
   "quantity": 1,
   "amount": 1500,
   "paymentMethod": "cashOnDelivery",
   "customizeName": "Faizan",
   "weight": "2.5g",
   "customer": {
       "fullName": "Anas Subzwari",
       "age": 20,
       "country": "Pakistan",
       "city": "Karachi",
       "address": "B-17/519, Indus Mehran Society",
       "contactNumber": "+923132953154"
   },
  "products": [
     {
        "name": "test10 product",
        "description": "Customize blue color vaaulid with picture printing",
        "cost": 700,
        "price": 1200,
        "weight": "2.3g"
    },
    {
        "name": "Customize vaulid",
        "description": "Customize blue color vaaulid with picture printing",
        "cost": 700,
        "price": 1200,
        "weight": "2.3g"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting this error

```
UpdateValuesMissingError: Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated values.

{"statusCode":500,"timestamp":"2023-02-25T18:06:43.623Z","path":"/orders","method":"POST","errorName":"UpdateValuesMissingError","message":"Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call \"qb.set(...)\" method to specify updated values."}
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Can you create a small repo to check? How are you getting the `orderRepository`?

Comment: I have updated my question, now you can check in the question that how am i getting the `orderRepository`

Comment: This `dto` is unrelated here. Instead, please share the order and customer entities.

Comment: i suggest you to enabled the logger of typeorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create the customer frist before you save or get the customer if he is saved
products is same issue

```
async createOrder(order: CreateOrderDto) {
  // you can make it transaction to applay (ACID)
  const customer = await this.customerRepository.save(order.customer);
  //  if customer is already saved in database not a new entity only get this entity by id or what ever
  //  const customer =  await this.customerRepository.findOne({where : {id :order.customer.id}});
  const products = await this.productsRepository.find({where : {id : In(customer.products.map(p=>p.id))}}
  const newOrder = await this.orderRepository.save({...order, customer : newCustomer, products});
  return newOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relationship between table order and customer like this.

```js
import { Entity, ManyToOne } from "typeorm"
import { Customer } from "./Customer" 
 
 @Entity()
export class Order {

   @ManyToOne(() => Customer, (customer) => customer.order)
    customer: Customer
    
}
```

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not share your entities, just make sure you have the following entities...

*order.entity.ts*

```
@Entity()
export class Order {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // Your columns for Order...

  @ManyToOne(() => Customer, customer => customer.orders)
  customer: Customer;

  @OneToMany(() => Product, product => product.order)
  products: Product[];
}
```

Then you also need `customer.entity.ts` and `product.entity.ts`.

In `customer.entity.ts`, your entity should have the following...

```
@Entity
export class Customer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  // Your other columns ...

  @OneToOne(() => Order, order => order.customer)
  order: Order;
}
```

Then in `product.entity.ts`...

```
@Entity
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // Your other columns ...

  @ManyToOne(() => Order, order => order.products)
  order: Order;
}
```